# Prove that F $ \in \mathbb{R} $ is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequences contained in F has a limit that is also an element of F.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm a novice at proofs so I like to write out everything, so please bear with me!. I understand that this is a biconditional statement, and I will have to prove it in the forward and reverse direction. To prove that every Cauchy sequence contained in F has a limit point that is also contained in F if F is closed, I will start with the forward direction:

Assume F $ \in \mathbb{R} $. If F is closed, then the limits of the Cauchy sequences of F are contained in F. By definition, a closed set is a set that contains all of its limit points. By definition, a Cauchy sequence is a sequence ($x_n$) if for all $ \epsilon > 0 $ there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ m, n \geq N $ implies that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon $. To prove that a Cauchy sequence's limit is contained in F, I need to find two arbitrary points, namely $ x_n $ and $ x_m $ whose distance between each other are less than $\epsilon$. I find an m and n that are greater than or equal to N. If I make N large enough that $ 1/N < \epsilon $, then $1/n$ and $1/m$ must be less than $\epsilon$ as well. The distance between $x_n$ and $x_m$ will be so arbitrarily small that it will be less than $\epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We have

$|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$ in which n, m $\geq$ N and N is large enough so that $1/N < \epsilon$.

$|x_n - x + x - x_m| < \epsilon $. Setting $|x_n - x| < \epsilon/2$ and $|x_m - x| < \epsilon/2$ and using the triangle inequality, we have

$\leq |x_n - x| + |x - x_m| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

This shows that the sequence converges, correct? I'm a little confused at this point. I am trying to show that the Cauchy sequence converges to some limit L, and that L is contained in F, making F a closed set. Could someone help me here? I feel like I've done nothing but restate definitions...

For the reverse direction, assume F $\in \mathbb{R}$. If the limits of the Cauchy sequences of F are contained in F, then F is closed. I feel that this is very much true after having proven the forward direction, and that stating the definition of a closed set would suffice here? Please let me know.

Comment: In general, a set in a metric space is closed iff it contains its limit points. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete, this is equivalent to the Cauchy condition in question.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a lot of definitions, really.

Suppose $F$ is closed. Suppose $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, with all $x_n \in F$. Then this sequence is Cauchy in the reals (which is complete), so $x_n \rightarrow p$ for some $p \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $p$ is a limit point of $F$ (why?) and so as $F$ is closed, $p \in F$. Hence the Cauchy sequence has a limit in $F$.

On the other hand, suppose all Cauchy sequences from $F$ converge to some point from $F$. Suppose $F$ were not closed, then there would be a limit point $p$ of $F$ that is not in $F$. Now, for every $n$ pick a point $x_n \in F \cap B(p,\frac{1}{n})$ by being a limit point of $F$. Then $x_n \rightarrow p$ in the reals, so $(x_n)$ is Cauchy (all convergent sequences are Cauchy) in $F$ (as all $x_n$ are in $F$). So it has a limit $q \in F$. But limits of sequences are unique, so this would imply $p= q$, but $p \notin F, q \in F$, contradiction. So $F$ is closed.

Comment: Your first line is good! One should not get lost in the definitions and instead focus on the essential idea which is embodied in the definition (of closed sets in the current question).+1

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Sir without constructing the sequence how could I tell '$\left( x_n \right)$ is Cauchy, with all $x_n\in F$'? Or it's not a matter at all. thanks in advance

Comment: @emonhossain By the triangle inequality, $d(x_n,x_m) \le \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$, and so if $\varepsilon>0$ is given, pick $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and then $d(x_n,x_m) < \varepsilon$ whenever $n,m \ge N$, so the sequence is Cauchy (this is in essence the convergent implies Cauchy argument).

Comment: Got it @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add an answer that made sense for me after tackling it a bit and drawing inspiration from here. The definitions I will be going by are from *"Understanding analysis"* by Stephen Abbott which I believe the post author stumbled onto this.

Just for notation used a bit below
(Epsilon neighbourhood)

> $V_\epsilon(a):= \{x\in\mathbb{R}: \lvert x-a\lvert <\epsilon\} = (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$

(Punctured epsilon neighbourhood)

> $V_\epsilon(a)\setminus\{a\}:= \{x\in\mathbb{R}: 0<\lvert x-a\lvert <\epsilon\} = (a-\epsilon, a)\cup(a, a+\epsilon)$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a closed set, that is it contains it's limit points. Given an arbitrary Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ by theorem 2.6.2 ( *A sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence* ) this sequence, let us denote it $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and let us denote the limit by $a$.

Now either $a_n\neq a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then $a$ is a limit point, since given any $\epsilon>0$, we can find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ where for all $n\geq N$ we have that $a_n\in V_\epsilon(a)\setminus\{a\}$, thus $V_\epsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\neq \emptyset$. By our assumption $F$ is closed, that is contains it's limit points so $a\in F$.

or alternately $a_n=a$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but then $a\in F$ since the sequence is contained in $F$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that every Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ has a limit also contained in $F$. Given an arbitrary limit point of $F$ denoted as $x$, by theorem 3.2.5 there is a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ contained in $F$ where $a_n\neq x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = x$. Again since the sequence is convergent by theorem 2.6.2 it is a Cauchy sequence thus the limit point $x\in F$ by assumption. $\blacksquare$