# Prove that F $\subseteq$ R is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequences contained in F has a limit that is also an element of F.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, alternative-proof

This same question was found here: [Prove that F $ \in \mathbb{R} $ is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequences contained in F has a limit that is also an element of F.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804552/prove-that-f-in-mathbbr-is-closed-if-and-only-if-every-cauchy-sequences) The OP / responses took a different path than what I am presenting here. I am presenting my own proof to see what could be worked on.

"A set F $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed $\textbf{iff}$ every cauchy sequence contained in F has a limit that is also an element of F."

$\textbf{Theorem 3.2.5}$: limit points of a set imply that the set has a convergent sequence to that limit point

$\textbf{Theorem 2.6.2}$: Cauchy sequences are convergent

(Both of the above theorems are "if and only if" theorems)

$\textbf{My attempt}$

($\underline{forward}$) Assume a set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Note that if F is empty we have a trivial case. So, lets assume F is non-empty and that there exists a Cauchy sequence, $(a_n)$, in F. By Theorem 2.6.2, $(a_n)$ converges to some limit, call it a. By definition, "a" is a limit point. Since F is closed, $a \in F$.

($\underline{backwards}$) Assume we have a set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that every Cauchy sequence in F has a limit that is also in F. Then, by Theorem 2.6.2, these sequences are convergent. Now, by Theorem 3.2.5, each of these limits are actually a limit point of F. Since all of the limit points were assumed to be in F, F is closed.

Comment: The _forward_ part is not good. You need to prove **every Cauchy sequence** in $F$ converges to a point in $F$, instead of proving **every point** in $F$ has a Cauchy sequence converges to it.

Comment: It's OK. But could use some improvement..... "This implies that F has limit points." should simply be deleted. It's irrelevant and incorrect. The empty set is closed but has no limit points..... "Assume X is a limit point in F" should say "of F". ("In F" usually means a member, or members of F.).... Grammar :(last section) "Each of these limit points are..." : "Is", not "are."

Comment: @user254665 If F is closed and we assume F is non-empty (empty is the trivial case), should I then assume F has a cauchy sequence in it? If so, would I use a similar argument and argue that every cauchy sequence converges giving me a limit point? (or start there?)

Comment: If $p\in F$ and $x_n=p$ for every $n$ then $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $F.$  See the comment by Cave Johnson.

Comment: @user254665 Do not limit points have to have a term in the convergent sequence not equal to the limit point? Also, I took another look at johnson's comments and updated the forward part.

Comment: The def'ns of convergent sequence and of Cauchy  sequence do  not exclude  the case where $x_n=p$ for infinitely many $n.$  On re-reading, I am no longer sure which def'n of closed you are starting from. There are different (provably equivalent ) def'ns.