# $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ closed if and only if every Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ has a limit that is also an element of $F$

Tags: real-analysis

It's the same question than in [Prove that F $\subseteq$ R is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequences contained in F has a limit that is also an element of F.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967734/prove-that-f-subseteq-r-is-closed-if-and-only-if-every-cauchy-sequences-conta). Im following the same analysis book (Abott). I have a doubt with the left to right implication ($\implies$) proof provided by 
the instructor manual. That's the following

---

Used definitions and theorems

**Theorem 3.2.5** A point $x$ is a limit point of a set A if and only if $x = \lim a_n$ for some sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ satisfying $a_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Definition 3.2.7** A set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if it contains all its limit points.

---

**Theorem to prove** $F \subseteq {\rm I\!R}$ closed if and only if every Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ has a limit that is also an element of $F$

$(\implies)$

Instructor manual

Assume that the set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Then $F$ contains its limit points. We will show that that every Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $F$ has its limit in $F$ by showing that the limit of $(a_n)$  is either a limit point or possibly an isolated point of $F$. Because $(a_n)$  is Cauchy, we know $\lim a_n$ exists. If $a_n \neq x$ for all $x$, then it follows from Theorem 3.2.5 that $x$ is a limit point of $F$. Now consider a Cauchy sequence $a_n$ where $a_n = x$ for some $n$. Because $(a_n) \subseteq F$ it follows that $x \in F$ as well. (Note that if an is eventually equal to $x$, then it may not be true that $x$ is a limit point of $F$.)

---

The problem I have with this proof is the line where it says

> Now consider a Cauchy sequence $a_n$ where $a_n = x$ for some $n$.
>   Because $(a_n) \subseteq F$ it follows that $x \in F$ as well.

We can't apply theorem 3.2.5 ($\Longleftarrow$), because there are some values of the sequence where $a_n = x$

I would solve this issue the following way:

If $a_n = x$ happens a finite number of times I would create the subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ where the values $a_n = x$ are skipped. This subsequence converges to the same limit $x$, and it's possible to use theorem 3.2.5 to assert that it's a limit point thus $x \in F$.

Otherwise, if $a_n = x$ an infinite number of times we can take the subsequence $a_{n_k}$ where $a_{n_k} = x$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, because $x \in (a_n) \subseteq F$ the limit $x \in F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re making it much harder than it really is: if $a_n=x$ for some $n$, then certainly $x\in F$, because by hypothesis $a_n\in F$. That’s it: you’re done. Remember, the goal is to prove that the limit $x$ is in $F$, and in this case there’s actually nothing to prove.

What you’ve done is not incorrect; it’s simply unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

If there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x=a_n.$ Then $x \in F$ because $a_n\in F.$ This is in fact the trivial case.